# Is window.print() supported on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, web, oracle-apex

I've seen many "old" threads on the internet that says `window.print()` is not supported on Android to print web pages. I tried it in my application that's build using Oracle APEX 22.1.4. and it worked. Which made me ask if the say of "it does not work" is old, and how old? What Android versions and web browsers versions that support it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print?retiredLocale=de#browser_compatibility

Comment: What's meant by the number "18" under "Chrome" in the link you provided? 
Does that mean that it has nothing to do with Android? Just the browser version?
What does the following mean...
"...this method is blocked inside an <iframe> unless its sandbox attribute has the value allow-modals."

Comment: Yes , it means that starting with version 18 of Chrome for Android it is supported. About the second question, I'm not sure what to answer, because this sentence already explains it very well I think... if `window.print` is called from within an IFrame, the call is blocked, unless the IFrame is set to allow modals using the corresponding sandbox attribute, which by default is off (see https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/block-modal-dialogs-sandboxed-iframe/). This is the same for `window.alert`, `window.confirm` and `window.prompt`.

Comment: Kindly, convert your comments into an answer to mark it as a correct answer.